# Execute PHP-Function if the current session expires

Tags: php

I am saving every login and logoff-action of a user (with the current timestamp when the event happens).
Now I need to handle the scenario, that a user doesn't log-off, but his session expires.

What's the best way, to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), which allows you to write your own GC handler. This GC handler will automatically be called by the PHP system based on the current [PHP configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability). You can use it to clean up your login sessions and trigger a logout.

However, you don't just write your own PHP session handler. It's way to error prone to do so and not advisable. Instead of checking for timed out sessions you save and check the last user action time in the database. Then you can use a small script/function which will be called periodically and checks if the last user action was too long ago (and the user hasn't been logged out yet). When you have found such users you can perform the already implemented logoff action.